# problem with wordpress author profile page URL

Tags: blog, author-template

I have a problem with my wordpress [blog here](http://muraliprashanth.me). everything seems to be working fine but the problem is after each post i am appending author information like the image below

[image: Murali Prashanth]

but when i click on the

> View all posts by Murali Prashanth hyperlink

it's redirecting me to this URL http://muraliprashanth.me/author/Murali%20Prashanth/ 
I don't know where to create the author profile page or does my wordpress theme supports author profile pages or not Please suggest me i am struggling to resolve this issue from past 3 months, Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

How are you creating the author's link?

If you put in your template:

```
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
```

It will write the author's name and link for the current post.

To modify the template for the author page, wordpress search for the following files in your theme's folder (in this order):

1. author-{nicename}.php
2. author-{id}.php
3. author.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php

Comment: yes i have author.php page

Comment: can you put here the code you use to write the author information?

Comment: this is the sample code i am using codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Sample_Template_File

Comment: no, I mean what you use in single post to show the author's link.

Comment: i used cool author box plugin to add author information

Comment: try one thing, open your single post template file, and somewhere in the template write <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> and check what's the author link and if that link works ok

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have author.php file.

Make sure you have author.php file.

sample author.php code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">

<!-- This sets the $curauth variable -->

    <?php
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
    ?>

    <h2>About: <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></h2>
    <dl>
        <dt>Website</dt>
        <dd><a href="<?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?>"><?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?></a></dd>
        <dt>Profile</dt>
        <dd><?php echo $curauth->user_description; ?></dd>
    </dl>

    <h2>Posts by <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?>:</h2>

    <ul>
<!-- The Loop -->

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?></a>,
            <?php the_time('d M Y'); ?> in <?php the_category('&');?>
        </li>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

<!-- End Loop -->

    </ul>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: yes i got the author.php page check this out http://muraliprashanth.me/wp-content/themes/admired/author.php

Comment: It might be permalinks problem. Just goto `permalinks settings ->  default -> save changes` then roll back